# Insert Image Header in Navigation Drawer Fragment with API 15

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-support-design

Whats the better way to Insert Image Header in Navigation Drawer Fragment with API 15? I know how put it with api 21, but i need to know this other method, if it is possible.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any issues adding the header?

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationView` is in android support design library, you can add header layout in prior versions. Adding should be the same in all versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same by adding the support library for more detaol [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)